# What renders PWA after adding to homescreen

Tags: android, web, progressive-web-apps

I was thinking about learning more about a progressive web app. As a demo, I wanted to implement simple music player that can work even after the screen is locked.

My question is what happens to PWA after being added to homescreen are all Chrome features as playing music in the [background](https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/media-session/audio.html) still supported? AND, How is PWA rendered, what is behind rendering (some webView or instance of chrome)?